# Ruby - How to take two arrays of strings and return an array with all of the combinations of the items in them, listing the first items first

Tags: ruby, arrays

My goal is to go from this:

```
first = ["on","in"]
second = ["to","set"]
```

to this:

```
["onto", "onset", "into", "inset"]
```

I want to achieve this using a method, so far this is the closest I can get:

```
def combinations(array_one,array_two)
    results = []
    array_one.each do |x|
        array_two.each do |y|
            results << ["#{x}#{y}"]
        end
    end
    results
end
```

This returns: `[["onto"], ["onset"], ["into"], ["inset"]]`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
def combinations(first, second)
  first.product(second).map(&:join)
end

combinations(%w(on in), %w(to set))
# => ["onto", "onset", "into", "inset"]
```

Comment: This works great, appreciate it! I'm curious though, how would you go about solving this without using .product?

Comment: @MichaelBart your approach is correct, but instead of `results << ["#{x}#{y}"]` you should have `results << "#{x}#{y}"`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-product)?

```
first = ["on","in"]
second = ["to","set"]

first.product(second).map(&:join) #=> ["onto", "onset", "into", "inset"]
```